# 2 out of 3 values gets to next page, first doesnt

Tags: php, html, mysql

as the title says, it sends 2 out of 3 values. Im fairly new at php, html coding and the uses of mysql servers so im not sure what the error is.
Btw my project is to make a "Rent a car" site.
First site should be choose car brand, customer and city (sry for swedish, some of the code is in english)
Site#1
https://gyazo.com/86bd55f87f75950013f2c5f3d7466848
code#1

```
<form action="carsite.php" method="GET">
        <table>
            <tr>
                <th>1.Välj Model</th>
                <td>
                    <p>
                        <select value="car">
                        <option disabled selected value="">Välj Model</option>
                            <?php foreach($res as $row){?>
                                    <option value="<?php echo htmlspecialchars($row->);?>"><?php echo htmlspecialchars($row->make);?></option><?php
                                }
                            ?>

                        </select>                               
                    </p>
                </td>
            </tr>
                <tr>
                    <th>2.Välj Kund</th>
                        <td>
                            <p>
                                <select name="customer">
                                    <option disabled selected value="">Välj Kund</option>
                                        <?php foreach($res2 as  $row2){?>
                                            <option value="<?php echo htmlspecialchars($row2->id);?>"><?php echo htmlspecialchars($row2->lname);?> <?php echo htmlspecialchars($row2->fname);?></option><?php
                                            }
                                        ?>
                                </select>                               
                            </p>
                        </td>
                </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <th>3.Välj Stad</th>
                        <td>
                            <p>
                                <select name="city">
                                    <option disabled selected value="">Välj Stad</option>
                                        <?php foreach($res3 as  $row3){?>

                                            <option value="<?php echo htmlspecialchars($row3->id);?>"><?php echo htmlspecialchars($row3->city);?></option><?php
                                            }
                                        ?>
                                </select>                               
                            </p>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
            </table>
        <input type="submit" value="Sök">
    </form>
```

in my eyes theres nothing wrong. (it sends the id from the tables in mysql)
but at the next site im getting 2/3 values i sent from first page.
Site#2

> Notice: Undefined index: car in F:\xamp\htdocs\Slutproject\carsite.php on line 7
>   12

(12 there is acctually id(customer id) 1 and id 2(city id))

So my problem is why does it send id 2 and 3 but not first one even though they were copy pasted from first id part (the codes of line).
I have tried sending it with GET so i could see the values uptop, still nothing about the car id.

//Mikael

Comment: `<?php echo htmlspecialchars($row->);?>` is wrong in your first `<select>` loop.  `$row` invokes no method

Comment: i just forgot to put that back ,sry!.

Comment: <option value="<?php echo htmlspecialchars($row->id);?>"><?php echo htmlspecialchars($row->make);?></option><?php thats how it should look and still doesnt work, thats why i have no idé why it aint working :/

Comment: `<select value="car">`   ----- you meant to put `name="car"`.

Comment: thanks man, i can believe i missed that, thanks for the help!.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your first `<select>` tag has a typo. It should be `<select name="car">`.

Comment: i cant belive i did that misstake, it works now thx, really mean it!